# Connect from Mac OS to Windows - cannot connect

Tags: windows, firewall

I have Mac and if I do

```
 nc -vz 192.168.1.13 777
```

I got

```
nc: connectx to 192.168.1.13 port 777 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
```

`192.168.1.13` is a Windows machine in the local network. I have enabled port `777` on Windows Firewall (I am using the built-in one). I have also tried other ports, but with the same result.

If I disable firewall altogether, I got:

```
nc: connectx to 192.168.1.13 port 777 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

However, in both cases, I can't get through with "succeeded". What am I missing?

Comment: Is anything listening on port 777?

Comment: I have also tried different ports with the same outcome.

Comment: Is anything listening on the ports you're testing? If nothing's listening, then of course you will get a connection refused!

Comment: Oh... my mistake. I was thinking that i will just check port before running the app. Thanks. It solved the "problem".. Post it as answer, please